# Paypal integration in an iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, appstore-approval, authorize.net

As per the apple guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) I found that we are not supposed to use In App purchase to buy/sell physical goods, I am building an iOS app to buy/sell some physical goods,

Does apple approve my the app if I use Paypal and authorize.net payment gateways in my app to buy/sell physical goods?

If apple allow us to use these third party payment gateway, whats the apple share? what % does apple takes for each paypal/credit card transaction?
 ( I know Apple takes 30% for In APP purchases(IAP) does this applicable to paypal/authorize.net ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing can be said with 100 % certainty But yes Apple allows you to sell physical goods using your own payment methods.

So you can include paypal or any other you want for this .

As for as apple share is concerned no they won't take any star in this case but service provider (like paypal) will charge their transaction fee as per their fee structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
hear is the link that you can download demo :-https://github.com/kristianmandrup/paypal-billing-demo

and I was implement in my app 

#in AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                           PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"AeB0tbkw-z4Ys3NvxekUZxnVNk26WXRodQBETFG4x-HtQAuqBf5k4edWOn2zia_l8RWBFJGEUNSVWJWg"}];

    return YES;
}
#with your Controller

#in your .h File set delegate

@interface MyCart : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PayPalConfiguration *payPalConfig;

#in your .m File

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSString *environment=@"sandbox";
    self.environment = environment;
    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:environment];


 _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"ScanPay";
    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];

    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];

    _payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal;


}
#Code with purchase button event

-(IBAction)btnCheckoutTapped
{
//    UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ScanPay" message:@"Under Development" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//    [alt show];

    NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithDouble:Price];

    // Optional: include payment details
    NSDecimalNumber *shipping = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0.00"];
    NSDecimalNumber *tax = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0.00"];
    PayPalPaymentDetails *paymentDetails = [PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetailsWithSubtotal:subtotal
                                                                               withShipping:shipping
                                                                                    withTax:tax];
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [[subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping] decimalNumberByAdding:tax];

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = total;
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = @"You Pay";
    payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil
    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }
    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                     delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
#PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    [self ErrorWithString:@"PayPal Payment Success!"];



    self.resultText = [completedPayment description];
    //[self showSuccess];

    [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    ReceiptScreen *obj=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReceiptScreen"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
    self.resultText = nil;
  //  self.successView.hidden = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
    NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
}
```